# SQL Server Distinct query with multiple conditional counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, aggregate

I am trying to create a query to provide me with the turnaround time in minutes of a number of rows of testing data.

A succinct version of the table is:

TestName, StartDateTime, EndDateTime

And I am looking for a query that can give me a output something like:

```
Distinct TestName 
, StartDate[not time]
, Count(rows) as Total
, Count(rows where datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) <=60) as NonBreach
, Count(rows where datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) >60) as Breach
, Count(rows where datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) >60) / Count(rows) as BreachRate
```

Is this principle even possible?

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can also always join results form different queries on TestName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT  TestName,
        CAST(StartdateTime AS DATE) AS StartDate,
        COUNT(*) AS Total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) <= 60 THEN 1 END) AS NonBreach,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) > 60 THEN 1 END) AS Breach,
        1.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) > 60 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(1) AS BreachRate
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY TestName, CAST(StartdateTime AS DATE)
```

Although depending on your DBMS you may need to use a different method of removing the time from the date.

---

Removing time from date:

---

**[SQL-Server 2008](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78a77/1)** and later:

```
SELECT  CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
```

---

**[SQL-Server 2005](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78a77/2)** and Earlier

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

---

**[MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78a77/21) & [SQLite](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/78a77/4)**

```
SELECT  DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

---

**[Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78a77/6)**

```
SELECT  TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

---

**[Postgresql](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/78a77/5)**

```
SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE
```

---

Comment: +1 for your `1.0 *` method of converting to decimal. But you have a two `Startdate` column names that are `StartDateTime` in the OP.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann Thanks. Edited and changed to `StartDateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL Server 2008 syntax (other databases have slightly different methods for `datediff` and `cast(... as date)`:

```
select  TestName 
,       cast(StartDateTime as date) as StartDate
,       count(*) as Total
,       sum(case when datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) <= 60 
            then 1 end) as NonBreach
,       sum(case when datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) > 60 
            then 1 end) as Breach
,       1.0 * sum(case when datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) > 60 
            then 1 end) / count(*) as BreachRate
from    YourTable
group by
        TestName 
,       cast(StartDateTime as date)
```

Comment: Thanks so much - what a muppet - so simple; my head just got caught on needing distinct tests.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to do it like this.
Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
Select TestName 
    , StartDate[not time]
    , Count(rows) as Total
    , SUM(CASE WHEN  datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) <=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as NonBreach
    , SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) >60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as Breach
```

Comment: You can't use distinct and aggregates (like sum or count) in the same query

Comment: Your right, I just copied the question and didn't change it. sorry